# Python -SQL String Escape Wildcards

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I tried to see if this question had been asked, which it probably has, but I couldn't find an answer.  I am querying MS SQL Server from a python script using pyodbc.

I am defining a function to query SQL.  The query string has both a '%R_%' which is meant as a wildcard for SQL to interpret, but also a '%s' which is meant to place a variable in python between single quotes.  It looks like this:

```
def numcust(matter):
    QryString = """
    select count(distinct user_id)
    from dbo.tbl_case_details
    where request like '%r_%'
    and project_id in
        (
        select distinct project_id
        from dbo.tbl_projects
        where matter_number = '%s'
        );
    """ % matter
    cursor.execute(QryString)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row[0]
```

How can I escape the wildcards for r_ so that I can successfully pass it through to SQL?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double the `%` where you want to escape them (i.e. `'%%r_%%'`).
Also, interpolate the string in the `cursor.execute` function like so:

```
cursor.execute(QryString, matter)
```

Answer (score 1):

`"%% %s"%("Hello",)` two % signs should become one after applying the %s stuff ...

but really you should be using the built in query stuff stuff

```
QryString = """
select count(distinct user_id)
from dbo.tbl_case_details
where request like '%r_%'
and project_id in
    (
    select distinct project_id
    from dbo.tbl_projects
    where matter_number = '%s'
    );
"""
cursor.execute(QryString,matter)
```

although you still may need to do `%%` for a literal `%`